# Passing variable in php as a parameter to mongodb remove() function

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to remove a document in mongodb-php. I am accepting an id from the user and using that I want to delete the document but it gives me an error

> "Deprecated: MongoCollection::remove(): Passing scalar values for the 
>   options parameter is deprecated and will be removed in the near future 
>   in C:\wamp\www..process.php on line 12".

here is my code

```
<?php  
$m = new mongo();
echo "Connection to database successfully";
$db = $m->mydb;
echo "Database mydb selected";
$collection = $db->mycollection;
echo "Collection selected succsessfully";
$collection->remove(array("Team_ID"=>$_POST['team_id']),false);
echo "Documents deleted successfully";
$cursor = $collection->find();
// iterate cursor to display team_id of documents
echo "Updated document";
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
echo $document["Team_ID"] . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, it doesn't accept scalar values as a second parameter. Instead, use an array with options (http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php).

```
$collection->remove(array('Team_ID' => $_POST['team_id']), array('justOne' => false));
```

As "justOne" is false by default, you can omit the second parameter.

```
$collection->remove(array('Team_ID' => $_POST['team_id']));
```